# Selenium - "No such element" Exception. No iFrame and explicit wait method cannot resolve the issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find the element of a button (either the "Download" or "Save selected series codes" buttons) of a webpage but I am unable to do so with whichever method I try. The webpage does not have an iFrame, the explicit wait method does not work, and in fact, even worse, when I iterate through all classes of the webpage, the element doesn't show up, while some elements that do not appear in the 'inspect elements' of chrome, do.

```
x = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class]')
for y in x:
    print(y.get_attribute('class'))
```

Furthermore, another unexpected issue is the following:

The `<div class="contentsInner">` element, which has the following three children,

```
<div class="frameDecorationPlane clearfix">
<div class="abstractResultArea">
<div class="contentsBorder">
```

Can be located, either with xpath or css selector, but except for the first child element, the remaining two raise a no such element error.

I have included a screenshot of the webpage that I am referring to below, for reference.

[image: Screenshot of the "Result of Search" page of the website.]

Lastly, I have included below the code that I have used to get to the website's page that raises the error. In order to replicate the error, you can use the following [link](http://www.stat-search.boj.or.jp/ssi/cgi-bin/famecgi2?cgi=$nme_a000_en&lstSelection=PR01), and just select any random item and any output year range and just click the 'search' button. You don't necessarily have to select specifically the data that I have selected for export.

```
# We open a browser window.
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/George/chromedriver_80', chrome_options=chromeOptions)

# We load the website's query:
browser.get('http://www.stat-search.boj.or.jp/ssi/cgi-bin/famecgi2?cgi=$nme_a000_en&lstSelection=PR01')

# Finds and clicks the Corporate Goods Price Index (2015 base) element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the Producer Price Index element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the All commodities element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and ticks the PR01'PRCG15_2200000000 PPI indicator element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#menuSearchDataCodeList > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > label')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the add to search condition button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.leafMenu > div:nth-child(6) > a')
element.click()

# Types into the 'From YYYY' output range.
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromYear').send_keys('1960') # The start year is '1960'.

# Finds and clicks the search button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#resultArea > div.abstractionMenuArea.clearfix > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)')
element.click()
```

After that, this is the line that raises the error:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below working solution. You need to switch to tab and then click on that element to download your report.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import win32com.client as comclt
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('http://www.stat-search.boj.or.jp/ssi/cgi-bin/famecgi2?cgi=$nme_a000_en&lstSelection=PR01')

# Finds and clicks the Corporate Goods Price Index (2015 base) element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the Producer Price Index element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the All commodities element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.selectMenuItem > table > tbody > tr.selectedMenu > td.menuNameCell')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the next button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.nodeMenu > div.resultCountPanel.clearfix > input')
element.click()

# Finds and ticks the PR01'PRCG15_2200000000 PPI indicator element.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#menuSearchDataCodeList > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > label')
element.click()

# Finds and clicks the add to search condition button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.contents > div > ul.tabContent > li:nth-child(1) > div.searchCondition > div.leafMenu > div:nth-child(6) > a')
element.click()

# Types into the 'From YYYY' output range.
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromYear').send_keys('1960') # The start year is '1960'.

# Finds and clicks the search button.
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#resultArea > div.abstractionMenuArea.clearfix > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)')
element.click()

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
print browser.title
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='littlelargeButton largeButton-download']"))).click();
```

**Output:** Kindly find below output once you click onto the download link

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to get the "//a[@class='littlelargeButton largeButton-download']" xpath? When I try to copy the xpath I get "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a". I am asking because I am not that familiar yet with these concepts. Thank you so much!

Comment: thats a Rel XPath, there are two types of xpath you are using absolute one. go through basic concepts. https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/. kindly hit upvote button